# RedisException Connection Refused

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, apache2

I am new to programming. I have an AWS EC2 instance which was working fine...

I have a Laravel project on it. I use Ubuntu and Apache2 on AWS EC2 instance.

I rebooted instance from AWS. When it comes online, I had the default Apache2 page like this:

[image: default apache2 page]

After that, I edited `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` file and changed `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to `DocumentRoot /var/www/merit/public` where my project is on.

After that it started to come up with this error;

```
RedisException - Connection refused
```

[image: RedisException - Connection refused]

When i tried to run `php artisan cache:clear` i got same error like;

```
   RedisException 

  Connection refused

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:161
    157▕         if (version_compare(phpversion('redis'), '5.3.0', '>=') && ! is_null($context = Arr::get($config, 'context'))) {
    158▕             $parameters[] = $context;
    159▕         }
    160▕ 
  ➜ 161▕         $client->{$persistent ? 'pconnect' : 'connect'}(...$parameters);
    162▕     }
    163▕ 
    164▕     /**
    165▕      * Create a new redis cluster instance.

      +25 vendor frames 
  26  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I didn't make any changes on `.env` file and I do not use redis neither.

What is the problem? Anyone can help or anyone got an idea?

Comment: Well someone thinks it is using redis, check your `.env` if it contains`redis`.